# Can one primary key be null when one entity has composite primary keys?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

*For Example;*
"library must keep track of the status of each book, its location, title, first author, and price (cost) for losses and late returns. **Books will be identified by their ISBN. In order to allow multiple copies of the same book, each book copy will have a unique ID number**"

So, in above scenario, I got ISBN and unique ID are composite primary keys of "Book" Entity. It is consider the unique ID if a book has multiple copies. Whenever a book has no multiple copies, it's not consider the unique ID. So, is unique ID possible to be null?

Comment: You will have 1 copy though wont you?

Answer (score 0):

- A Primary Key cannot be null; that is simply part of the definition.
- A table can have many "candidate keys", but only one can be designated as the Primary Key; that's what "primary" means in this context.
- Being null and having duplicate values are entirely separate things; null means "I don't know the value", or "this column is not applicable to this row", or similar ideas.
- Saying a column is sometimes unique and sometimes not makes no sense. Unique means that *every possible row has a different value*.

What you're possibly trying to describe is a case where *the combination of ISBN AND and identifier* is unique for every row, but each on its own is not. In that case, you have "a composite key" - a single key *composed* of multiple columns. In order to be used as the Primary Key, that composite key cannot contain nulls; but that's fine, simply assign a value of 0 or 1 to the first copy of each book.

An alternative interpretation of the requirement is that the identifier column *on its own* is unique, and independent of the ISBN. In that case, it will never have nulls, and will be suitable as a Primary Key in its own.